# FullCalendar.io. Unable to render background events

Tags: javascript, function, ionic-framework, fullcalendar

I'm following the example from this answer:

[How can I create an event based on pattern for calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773308/how-can-i-create-an-event-based-on-pattern-for-calendar)

There is a problem tho. When i try adding rendering the events in background mode(adding rendering: 'background'), the events doesn't show. However, when i remove it, the events show as is.

here is my code:

```
          events.push({
            title: schedule[s].title,
            color: schedule[s].color,
            // we have to clone because the add() call below mutates the date
            start: day.clone(),
            allday: true,
            rendering: 'background'<--putting this line causes error in events rendering. removing it(as per the tutorial) is okay.
          });
```

How can i make

Comment: Have you tried switching views? `Background events that are all-day will only be rendered in month view or the all-day slots of agenda view.`

Comment: yes. I'm trying to show it in month view. but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

That's because `allday` parameter is true. According to documentation:

> Background events that are **timed** will only be rendered on the time
>   slots in agenda view. Background events that are **all-day** will only be
>   rendered in month view or the all-day slots of agenda view.

Source: [Background-events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events)

Comment: if I want to use this code for month view, how can i modify it then? I tried agenda view and it shows fine.